# How to solve "Java Failed to write core dump ..." for Rstudio running in EMR

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, amazon-emr, sparklyr, rstudio-server

I'm running  a data preparation script with Sparklyr on Rstudio (running in EMR). The code exuction crashes and I got this error report I don't understand properly:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f99b77fb968, pid=12298, tid=0x00007f99b8167940
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_171-b10) (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.171-b10 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libR.so+0xbe968]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       32949048 kB
MemFree:        11480880 kB
MemAvailable:   19345760 kB
Buffers:          455776 kB
Cached:          5598268 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:         14572612 kB
Inactive:        3704688 kB
Active(anon):   12223280 kB
Inactive(anon):       48 kB
Active(file):    2349332 kB
Inactive(file):  3704640 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               748 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      12223264 kB
Mapped:           198336 kB
...
```

I want to know how to fix the problem so my code could run entirely ? 
Thanks in advance !